# Unable to connect to RDS using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have read countless guides and threads on how to connect to RDS database with MySQL Workbench and I do exactly as specified (I believe), but I still haven't managed to get a connection.

There must be something I am overlooking and simply don't understand. Let me know if I need to give more information. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

I have made sure that public accessibility is set to yes. Here is a summary of my database in RDS:

[image: Summary of the server in RDS]

And the configurations of my database:
[image: Configurations of my database]

I try to connect to the database with Standard (TCP/IP):
[image]

And get the following error every time:
[image]

For some reason nothing happens when I click "Test Connection", but at one point I got the error 10060. Don't know if this helps though. I tried googling it but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have been stuck at this for some time now and simply don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much,

cheers

Comment: Have you done what https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQVKe.png is suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have not open the port (3307) for your ip address in the used security groups.
Check the used security groups for inbound rule, allowing traffic to port 3307 from your ip address.

Simply click on the security group to get to the configuration page.

Here a hint:
[Screenshot of how to add a rule to a security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eaHg.png)

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much. I knew there was something simple I was missing.